# Determine what is wrong with the ”proof” trying to show that $42 \Bbb Z$ is the kernel for $f:6\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z_7, f(x)=[\frac{x}{6}]_7$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

> Determine what is wrong with the following ”proof” trying to show that $42 \Bbb Z$ is the kernel for the homomorphism $f:6\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z_7, f(x)=[\frac{x}{6}]_7$. Suppose $a\in 42\Bbb Z$, then $k=42k$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z$.  Now $$f(a)=f(42k)=[\frac{42k}{6}]_7 = [7k]_7 = [0]_7.$$

In the first line they’re taking $a \in 42\Bbb Z$, but then the line $k=42k$ should be $a=42k$ since $k=42k$ would imply $k=0$. However I’m not sure there is anything else that’s wrong here?

Comment: "$k=42k$" is probably not more than a typo.

Answer (score 2):

They show that, if $a\in 42\mathbb Z$, then $a$ is in the kernel. But to complete the proof, they must also show the converse: if $a$ is in the kernel, then $a\in 42\mathbb Z$. This part is missing from the "proof".

Comment: If $a \in \ker(f)$, then $f(a) = e$. Now the identity of $\Bbb Z_7$ is $[0]_7$, but every element in $42 \Bbb Z$ under $f$ gets mapped to $[0]_7$ so $a$ would be also in $42 \Bbb Z$?

Comment: But there isn’t a mistake in the proof? Just a part missing?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it's just that a part of the proof is missing, that's all. On the other hand, the part that is missing is the _difficult_ part of the proof (in my opinion). The suggestion in your comment, unfortunately, does not complete the proof. You have shown that every element in $42\mathbb Z$ is mapped to $[0]_7$, but we need to show the opposite: every element that is mapped to $[0]_7$ comes from $42\mathbb Z$.